# Unable to load dynamic library pdo_mysql.so

Tags: php

I installed php55-* because I needed to upgrade an SDK in my app (which ended up needing PHP 5.4 or later). It seems that `pdo_mysql.so` cannot be loaded:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/5.5/modules/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/5.5/modules/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

I know I don't have `pdo_mysql.so` in my modules dir. I do have `pdo_mysqlnd.so`. What is the difference?

I'm using Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.09 on EC2. I do have the php55-pdo package installed, as well as the php55-mysqlnd package.

Comment: What _exactly_ is your question?

Comment: I searched php.ini for the pdo_mysql.so string. It's not there. Where is this being referenced? Second, what is the difference between pdo_mysqlnd and pdo_mysql?

Comment: The latter question isn't really on topic here, and it's also [well covered in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php). I don't know why your system is trying to load a nonexistent module. It could just be yet another Amazon Linux problem (which are pretty much continuous)...